# Making custom TabView recognize tab item Nav bar when keyboard is active

Tags: swift, swiftui

Problem: Custom TabView does not recognise NavBar so its being pushed out of view when keyboard is active.

[image]
[image]

This is container code that wraps content and TabBarItems in Zstack. As content is made this way it contains all NavBar informations and that NavBar is being treated like any other view, its being pushed upwards when keyboard is active.

```
struct CustomTabBarContainerView<Content:View> : View {

@Binding var selection: TabBarItem
@State private var tabs: [TabBarItem] = []
let content: Content

init(selection: Binding<TabBarItem>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content){
    self._selection = selection
    self.content = content()
}
var body: some View {
    
    containerVersion2
    
}
}
  private var containerVersion2 : some View{
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom){

            content
        
            .zIndex(0)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack(spacing:15){
            
                CustomTabBarView(tabs: tabs, selection: $selection, localSelection: selection).zIndex(0)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

This is AppTabBar that is being used with custom implementation:

```
struct AppTabBarView: View {
@State private var selection: String = "home"
@State private var tabSelection: TabBarItem = .chat
var body: some View {
   //instead of apple default TabView we are going to use our custom that looks nearly the same

    CustomTabBarContainerView(selection: $tabSelection){
       
        ChatsView()//is wrapped with NavigationView as it contains chats to enter called ChatView()
        
            .tabBarItem(tab: .chat, selection: $tabSelection)//code for this is reddudant but this is also CUSTOM not default
        
        LogBackgroundView()
            .tabBarItem(tab: .upcoming, selection: $tabSelection)
      ...
    }
```

One possible solution is to wrap CustomTabBarContainerView with NavigationView here in AppTabBar struct and delete ChatsView NavigationView, that way NavBar works perfectly but I think it ugly solution for producion code.

I've tried adding `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)` to ChatView that is being navigated to but only efect i got was that only Hstack where is TextEdit and sendButton stays in place(not being pushed by keyboard) but scrollView where is conversation and NavBar above it is still being pushed.

```
    struct ChatView: View {

    var body: some View {
          
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Spacer()
       messagesView

               .padding(.vertical)
            }
            VStack(spacing:0){
                
                chatBottomBar
                   
            }              
        }
    
        .background(chatBackground,ignoresSafeAreaEdges: [.bottom])
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
       
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```

This is customTabBar resource I used as its concept is to be as similar as possible to apple TabView [Making custom TabView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxW9Dxt896U&t=2741s)

Comment: This code is not testable, needed minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Not sure what you try to do with your ZStack and all your CustomTabBar stuff. Where is the navigation view ? Tab bar inside navigation view or navigation view inside tab ? May using a segmented picker and ZStack is what you want to use.